# Не работают горячие клавиши в IntellijIdea

Tags: intellij-idea

В keymap по дефолту windows, плагин Ideavim не установлен...

Comment: Какие комбинации не работают? Какая версия intellij?

Answer (score 0):

Проблему решил сменой языка ОС.